# Retrieve Google Username in Gadget

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites, google-gadget

I have a bit of embed code that I need to place on a Google Site, this site will be restricted to our Google domain members. I can place this JavaScript in a Google Gadget and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://HOSTNAME/Forms/js/forms-embed.js?v=9.2'>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lfembed = new LaserficheForms.Form(null /*element to place form in*/,{bpid: '1', host:'https://HOSTNAME/Forms', params:PARAMS, autoheight: false}).getFrm();
    lfembed.style.height = "100%";
</script>
```

The problem is that I want to be able to get the currently logged in user's email address and pass that in the `params:` section of the code above.

From what I can tell, you can't do this within a Google Gadget. I *can* retrieve the current email address with the Google Apps Script object below, but I don't know how to make the two work together.

```
function doGet() {
  var gauser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput(gauser);
   return output;
}
```

Another problem is that Google sanitizes some of the JavaScript when I try to include all of the code in just the Google Apps Script.

I really don't have much experience in this area, so if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I learned about [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) today.

I ended up getting this to work by publishing the following Google Apps Script web app.

```
function doGet(request) {
  var gauser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    request.parameters.prefix + '(' + JSON.stringify(gauser) + ')')
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

Then I called the web app service via URL in my XML Gadget

```
<script src="https://WEBAPPURL?prefix=lfdo"></script>
```

This placed the username value into the `lfdo` function, which I inserted into the parameter string I needed it in.

The full Content section of the XML gadget:

```
<![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://HOSTNAME/Forms/js/forms-embed.js?v=9.2'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function lfdo(gauser) {
        console.log(gauser);
        var lfembed = new LaserficheForms.Form(null /*element to place form in*/,{bpid: '1', host:'https://HOSTNAME/Forms', params:'Name='+ gauser, autoheight: false}).getFrm();
        lfembed.style.height = "100%";
        gadgets.window.adjustHeight();
    }

</script>

<script src="https://WEBAPPURL?prefix=lfdo"></script>

]]>
```

[This article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages) on Google Developers set me in the right direction.

Comment: Just a note that this method only works in google apps domains.

Comment: The problem that I am facing with this is that the App Script has to be authorized by the logged in user. Unless user explicitly authorizes at least once it is failing.